Achieve callback/functions overloading in slint
Based on composition over inheritance recommendation , I would like to achieve a function or callback overloading to use in repetition element  or conditional element 
here is a simple example :
export enum PRINTER_TYPE { FOO, BAR}

export component fooPrinter {
function print() {
   content.text="foo";
}
content:=Text {}
   
}

export component barPrinter{
function print() {
   content.text="bar";
}
content:=Text {}

}

export component printerContainer {
in property <PRINTER-TYPE> type;
callback print();
if type==PRINTER-TYPE.FOO: myFoo:=fooPrinter {
/* not possible
   parent.print()=>{
   self.print();
   }
   */
}
if type==PRINTER-TYPE.BAR: myBar:=barPrinter{
/* not possible
   parent.print()=>{
   self.print();
   }
   */
}

For this I though i could do someting like this
export component printerContainer {
// ....
    public function print() {
        if (type == PRINTER-TYPE.FOO) {
            myFoo.printFoo();
        }
        if (type == PRINTER-TYPE.BAR) {
            myBar.printBar();
        }
    }

But i can't addres myFoo  either myBar
The only solution i found was :
export component printerContainer inherits Rectangle {

    in property <PRINTER-TYPE> printerType;
    in property <bool> selected;
    public function print() {
        if (printerType == PRINTER-TYPE.FOO) {
            foo.printFoo();
        }
        if (printerType == PRINTER-TYPE.BAR) {
            bar.printBar();
        }
    }
    foo := FooPrinter {
        x: 0;
        y: 0;
        selected <=> parent.selected;
        visible: printerType == PRINTER-TYPE.FOO;
    }
    bar := BarPrinter {
        x: 0;
        y: 0;
        selected <=> parent.selected;
        visible: printerType == PRINTER-TYPE.BAR;
    }
}

That is an okay solution ( except for the code generation of the not-visible elements in the container).
But The goal of a container is a serialization of the elements in an auto layout.
I would love to use it in a for-in statement but i am stuck since I can't predict the calls by direct component instance reference like the previous PrinterContainer.print() function.
I can really admit i don't have a good understanding of the slint architecture so if a simple solution exist i would be glad to hear it!
But i do think callback overloading might be a good functionality.
for example here is a detailed demo to play with

Here is a simple demo i have made

EDIT you have to run the * component WorkingDemo * in slintPad
It implements the aimed effect but without the repetition either the If statement.

Thank you in advance
Antoine
